# getting a error and I don"t know how to fix it

Tags: java

```
   String name;
   char type;
   int calroies;
   int protein;
   int fat;
   int sodium;
   int fiber;
   int carbohydrates;
   int sugar;
   int potassium;
   int vitamins;
   int shelf;
   double weight;
   double cups;
   double rating;

   public cereal (String cName, char cType, int cCalroies, int cProtein, int cFat, int cSodium, int cFiber, int cCarbohydrates, int cSugar, int cPotassium, int cVitamins, int cShelf, double cWeight, double cCups, double cRating)
   {
      name = cName;
      type = cType;
      calroies = cCalroies;
      protein = cProtein;
      fat = cFat;
      sodium = cSodium;
      fiber = cFiber;
      carbohydrates = cCarbohydrates;
      sugar = cSugar;
      potassium = cPotassium;
      vitamins = cVitamins;
      shelf = cShelf;
      weight = cWeight;
      cups = cCups;
      rating = cRating;
   }
   public String getName();
   {
      return name;
   }
   public char getType();
   {
      return type;
   }
   public String toString();
   {
      return ("Cereal Name:" + name + "Cereal Type:" + type + "Calroies" + calroies + "Protein" + protein + "Fat" + fat + "Sodium" + sodium + "Fiber" + fiber + "Carbohydrates" + carbohydrates + "Sugar" + sugar + "potassium" + potassium + "vitamins" + vitamins + "shelf" + shelf + "weight" + weight + "cups" + cups + "rating" + rating);
   }

   //runner
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      cereal fruityO = new cereal(fruityO, H, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
      fruityO.getName();
   }
}
```

So I'm trying to work on this project for school and I keep getting these errors. I am trying to call the funcition in my "runner" i put into my file.I labled it and its near the bottom of the code. I dont have much experence with java and i don't understand these errors so any help would be appreciated.

```
cereal.java:37: error: missing method body, or declare abstract
   public String getName();
                 ^
cereal.java:39: error: return outside method
      return name;
      ^
cereal.java:41: error: missing method body, or declare abstract
   public char getType();
               ^
cereal.java:43: error: return outside method
      return type;
      ^
cereal.java:45: error: missing method body, or declare abstract
   public String toString();
                 ^
cereal.java:47: error: return outside method
      return ("Cereal Name:" + name + "Cereal Type:" + type + "Calroies" + calroies + "Protein" + protein + "Fat" + fat + "Sodium" + sodium + "Fiber" + fiber + "Carbohydrates" + carbohydrates + "Sugar" + sugar + "potassium" + potassium + "vitamins" + vitamins + "shelf" + shelf + "weight" + weight + "cups" + cups + "rating" + rating);
      ^
cereal.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
      cereal fruityO = new cereal(fruityO, H, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
                                           ^
  symbol:   variable H
  location: class cereal
7 errors
```

Again, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Semicolons end a statement, so `getName(); { ... }` is a malformed method definition followed by an initializer block, not a method name followed by a method body.

Comment: _public String getName();_ Isn't the extra semicolon the issue?

Comment: Where's your class declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding extra semicolons to your methods. Check this out:

```
public String getName();
{
    return name;
}
```

if you add a semicolon right after the method signature you're telling the compiler you're done with the line. Thus, the compiler thinks you're trying to add an abstract method (one without body).

Try removing those semicolons and see how it goes.